# Background Object detection in face recognition Using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I have created a face recognition code using OpenCV. Now the problems occuring are :

-> Sometimes it detects small objects from the wall and show them as me. How can i stop it from doing so ? so that it only detect faces not objets.

-> Whenever a unknown person shows up on scree, it randomly shows any name to it from the database. I waant it to show as a Unknown Face whenever someone unknown hits the cam.

Note : i did not added it to sql database yet but will do it after i get through this.THanks for the help in advance

Data Set creator code:

```
import cv2
import sqlite3
import numpy as np

faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0);

id = raw_input('Enter Your ID : ')

Name = raw_input('Enter Your Name : ')

sampleNum=0;
while(True):
    ret,img=cam.read();
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5);
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        sampleNum=sampleNum+1;
        cv2.imwrite("dataSet/User."+str(id)+"."+str(sampleNum)+".jpg",gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])

        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        cv2.waitKey(500);
    cv2.imshow("Face",img);
    cv2.waitKey(1);
    if(sampleNum>20):
        break;
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Trainer Code :

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

recognizer=cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer();
path='dataSet'

def getImagesWithID(path):
    imagePaths=[os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
    faces=[]
    IDs=[]
    for imagePath in imagePaths:
        faceImg=Image.open(imagePath).convert('L');
        faceNp=np.array(faceImg,'uint8')
        ID=int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split('.')[1])
        faces.append(faceNp)
        print ID
        IDs.append(ID)
        cv2.imshow("training",faceNp)
        cv2.waitKey(10)
    return IDs, faces

Ids,faces=getImagesWithID(path)
recognizer.train(faces,np.array(Ids))
recognizer.save('recognizer/trainningData.yml')
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Detector Code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0);
rec=cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer();
rec.load("recognizer\\trainningData.yml")
id=0
font=cv2.cv.InitFont(cv2.cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,2,2,0,2)
while(True):
    ret,img=cam.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5);
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
        id,conf=rec.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        if(id==1):
            id="Vivek"
        cv2.cv.PutText(cv2.cv.fromarray(img),str(id),(x,y+h),font,255);
    cv2.imshow("Face",img); 
    if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q')):
        break;
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```